# A question about field extensions

Tags: field-theory

I read in Herstein that a field extension $K$ of field $F$ is a vector space over $F$, and its *degree* over $F$ is the number of base elements.

Let $K$ (field extension of $F$) be a vector space over $F$, and let its base elements be $k_{1},k_{2}\dots k_{n}$. If $K$ is a vector space over $F$, how will elements that are part of $K$ like $k_{1}k_{2}$ be represented by a simple scalar representation like $f_{1}k_{1}+f_{2}k_{2}\dots$? $f_{1},f_{2}\dots f_{n}$ are scalars $\in F$

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you try an example, like the extension $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ of $\mathbb Q$?  Find a basis of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ over $\mathbb Q$, and see how multiplication works in terms of that basis.

Comment: Another useful example if that of $\mathbb C$ seen as an extension of $\mathbb R$: find a basis of the former over th latter, and then see how multiplication works in terms of that basis/

Comment: Let's take the extension $Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ over $Q$ to be an example. I suppose the basis will have to consist of $1,\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}$. How will $\sqrt{6}$ be represented?

Comment: did you take a more complicated example than what I suggested? Do you completely understand my two examples? In any case, you say that «you **suppose** that the basis will consist of those three numbers» but until you actually **check** it is hard to answer you question in the comment!...

Comment: @Ayush: if you can't represent $\sqrt{6}$, perhaps your basis is not really a basis...

Comment: Let the basis be $b_{1},b_{2}\dots$. How would we represent $b_{1}b_{2}$ through a scalar-vector representation like $c_{1}b_{1}+c_{2}b_{2}\dots$? I might be repeating myself but this part still isn't clear to me.

Comment: I emphatically suggest you do the two examples I suggested and *then* the example of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2, \sqrt3)$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez- cool, I'll do that. Thanks :)

Comment: From what I can understand, and I might be wrong, $Q[\sqrt{2}]$ can be an extension of $Q$ if the basis consists of ${1,\sqrt{2}}$. The basis is so small because $\sqrt{2}*\sqrt{2}=2\in Q$. What about extending $Q$ to $Q[x]$ though? If $x^{n}\notin Q$ for any finite $n$, wouldn't the basis have to consist of ${1,x,x^{2}\dots}$- an infinite number of terms, all powers of $x$?

Comment: Ayush, if $x$ is a root of a polynomial (with rational coefficients) of degree $n$, then the set $\{{1,x,x^2,\dots,x^n\}}$ is linearly dependent over the rationals.